# Json Parsing in Apache Pig

Tags: json, parsing, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am Having a json :

```
{"Name":"sampling","elementInfo":{"fraction":"3"},"destination":"/user/sree/OUT","source":"/user/sree/foo.txt"}
```

I found that we are able to load json into PigScript.

```
A = LOAD ‘data.json’
USING PigJsonLoader();
```

But how to parse json in Apache Pig

```
--Sampling.pig
--pig -x mapreduce -f Sampling.pig -param input=foo.csv -param output=OUT/pig -param delimiter="," -param fraction='0.05'

--Load data
inputdata = LOAD '$input' using PigStorage('$delimiter');

--Group data
groupedByAll = group inputdata all;

--output into hdfs
sampled = SAMPLE inputdata $fraction;
store sampled into '$output' using PigStorage('$delimiter');
```

Above is my pig script.
How to `parse` json (each element) in Apache pig?
I need to take above json as input and parse its `source,delimiter,fraction,output` and pass in `$input,$delimiter,$fraction,$output` respectively.

How to parse the same .
Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
--Load data
inputdata = LOAD '/input.txt' using JsonLoader('Name:chararray,elementinfo:(fraction:chararray),destionation:chararray,source:chararray');

--Group data
groupedByAll = group inputdata all;

store groupedByAll into '/OUT/pig' using PigStorage(',');
```

Now your output looks :

```
all,{(sampling1,(4),/user/sree/OUT1,/user/sree/foo1.txt),(sampling,(3),/user/sree/OUT,/user/sree/foo.txt)}
```

In input file fraction data `{"fraction":"3"}` in double quotes. so i used fraction as chararray so can't able to run sample command so i used the above script to get the result.

if you want to perform sample operation cast the fraction data to int and then you will get the result.

Comment: Thanks MarHserus. But How to parse those elements?In order to achieve the fraction and delimiter?My input is :/user/sree/foo.txt

Comment: I expect the output as a file (not a json) with delimiter,which is same as input file(foo.txt)

Comment: Thanks for your kind heart foe runnig the same and posting.But still confusion exist.My usecase is like I have a json from the json I need to parse, what all inputs i need to run above pig code(sampling). thay means I need to parse the input file to be sampled,delimiter and output